# How does the (undocumented) return_value argument for unittest.mock.patch work?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, undocumented-behavior

I've seen examples of `unittest.mock.patch()` and `unittest.mock.patch.object()` directly using a `return_value` argument.

Example:

```
with patch.object(ProductionClass, 'method', return_value=None) as mock_method:
    thing = ProductionClass()
    thing.method(1, 2, 3)
```

However, this argument is not officially documented for `unittest.mock.patch()` nor `unittest.mock.patch.object()`.  (It is however used in the examples of the official documentation).

Is this supported or is it undefined behavior?  Is it supposed to be documented and isn't?  Do these examples work by coincidence?  What does this argument do; does it do something unintuitive, or is it self-explanatory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for [mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch):

> `patch()` takes arbitrary keyword arguments. These will be passed to `AsyncMock` if the patched object is asynchronous, to `MagicMock` otherwise or to `new_callable` if specified.

From the documentation of [mock.patch.object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object):

> Like `patch()`, `patch.object()` takes arbitrary keyword arguments for configuring the mock object it creates.

And from the documentation of [mock.Mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock), where it is actually used:

> `return_value`: The value returned when the mock is called. By default this is a new Mock (created on first access). See the `return_value` attribute.

And for good measure, the documentation of the `return_value` attribute, which shows the usage with examples:

Set this to configure the value returned by calling the mock:

```
>>> mock = Mock()
>>> mock.return_value = 'fish'
>>> mock()
'fish'
```

The default return value is a mock object and you can configure it in the normal way:

```
>>> mock = Mock()
>>> mock.return_value.attribute = sentinel.Attribute
>>> mock.return_value()
<Mock name='mock()()' id='...'>
>>> mock.return_value.assert_called_with()
```

`return_value` can also be set in the constructor:

```
>>> mock = Mock(return_value=3)
>>> mock.return_value
3
>>> mock()
3
```

So, as you can see, this is all well documented, though admittedly it may be overlooked at a first glance due to the arguments not present in the signature.

Comment: You're right.  It is there.  The function signature only has `kwargs`, and `kwargs` did not appear in the description.  ("Keyword arguments" did.)  It's all a bit dense, and can't really be used as a quick reference.  Anyway, thank you.